# Could someone explain this piece of code?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
k = 4
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.speed(200)
turtle.pensize(1)
turtle.pencolor("blue")
x = 3
while True:
    for i in range(1, x):
        t.forward(n)
        t.left(360/x)
    x = x + 1
```

A friend posted this on Facebook and as a beginner i'm not exactly sure how it works. Please explain.

Comment: Your code won't run. Do some fix and you will get nice turtle image.

Comment: what is "n" variable?

Comment: @AlirezaAfzalghaei I believe it is a typo and is should be `i`

Comment: Why are you asking us instead of your friend?

Answer (score 1):

Your friends code contains a few errors. I modified the code to look like the example below:

```
import turtle
k = 4
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(200)
t.pensize(1)
t.pencolor("blue")
x = 3
while True:
    for i in range(1, x):
        t.forward(i)
        t.left(360/x)
    x = x + 1
```

Nevertheless, Lets take it step by step:

1. The first line, `import turtle`, imports all the code written in a python file called turtle, into the file your in now. The turtle **module** allows you to draw lines and shapes using a virtual pen to draw them.
2. The next line, sets the variable `k` equal to the number `4`.
3. The third line is a bit hard to understand for a beginner, but basically what your doing is making a **turtle object** by using a class that was written in the turtle python file called `turtle.Turtle`. You should note that I'll cal our turtle object `t` not `turtle` as the module name your importing is named turtle already.
4. After creating our turtle object using turtle, it now has all the attributes and methods of the `turtle.Turtle` class. One of the methods available is called `speed()`. This controls the speed of your turtle when drawing lines or shapes.
5. The fourth line should be pretty self explanatory. On our `turtle.Turtle` object called `t`, we have another method called pen-size used to set the size of the pen used for drawing.
6. The Fifth line just uses another method in the `turtle.Turtle` class to set the pen-color for drawing, blue.
7. the sixth line sets the variable `x` equal to the number `3`
8. The next lines create a while-loop that will run forever. In that while-loop we tell python to:
9. run a for-loop in the range 1 to 3 exclusive. In other word, run the for-loop 1 time.
10. On each iteration of the **for-loop**, move our turtle pen forward 1 pixel.
11. On each iteration of the **for-loop**, move our turtle pen left 180 degrees.
12. The last and final line, increments the `x` variable by `1` number on each iteration of the **while-loop**, not the **for-loop**.

When the program is run, it will look something like the photo posted in Lyang's answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are some errors in the code, such that `k` is not used, `t` does not exist (`turtle = turtle.Turtle()` should be `t = turtle.Turtle()` instead). I am assuming that `n` should be `i` instead.

Turtle is a package from python, but it is not a required package so your code might not run on online interpreters. When it runs, it generates an image like this (in an animation):

[image]

Comment: The really does nothing to answer the main question, I'm afraid.